# на каком оборудовании лучше сделать следующий проект

Tags: wifi

Подскажите на каком оборудовании лучше сделать следующий проект
Задача построить беспроводную сеть высокой плотности на улице (спортивное мероприятие), с возможностью интеллектуально распределять клиентов по частоте и стандартам, который у них поддерживается на мобильном устройстве